# Express Matrix as sum of given Matrices

Tags: matrices

Lets say I have a matrix of interest as follows.
$$
A =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1&2\\
3&4\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Now, I also have two other matrices.
$$
x=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
0&0\\
\end{array}
\right] 
$$
$$
y=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0&0\\
1&1\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Now, $\text{diff} = A-(x+y)= \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
2&3\\
\end{array}
\right]$ here coefficients of $x$ and $y$ are $1$.

My question is: Is there way to get the coefficients such that the elements of $\text{diff}$ is as close to zero as possible.

My situation is that, I have a matrix $A$ and other matrices $x$, $y$, $z$, $\dots$ , what i want to do is get $\text{coeff}$ for $x$, $y$, $z$, $\dots$ to represent $A$ as their sum (exactly would be better but it may not be in all case, so as closely as possible). Is there any way to do this? Or code?

Comment: Sounds like an optimization problem. Perhaps you would like to define what exactly you mean by "elemets (...) are as close to zero as possible". A good approach would be to calculate one number (as a function of the final matrix) that represents this distance from zero. This would resolve the question of, for example, which one is better (closer to zero),
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{array}
\right]
\qquad \text{or} \qquad
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
2&0\\
0&0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: I am after [[2,0],[0,0]]  , by elements i mean elements of Matrix, here 2,0,0 and 0.

PS. Can you let me know how to type matrix. Thank You

Comment: Shiva: To see how to type matrices, please see how I the post was edited. The code is called MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not a "sum" of matrices but a "linear combination".

Basically you want to find numbers, a and b, such that
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}= a\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+ b\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a & a \\b & b\end{bmatrix}$  so that a= 1, a= 2, b= 3, and b= 4. Obviously that is impossible!

The problem is that $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$, belonging to the **four** dimensional space of all 2 by 2 matrices does not belong to the **two** dimensional subspace spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I am not looking for exact solution , I am looking for as close as possible ,such that the matrix after linear combination has 'most' of its elements equal to the original

e.g. if a 64x64 matrix 4096 elements, I would be happy if (lets say) 3500 elements same .
Thank you